# I want to change DataGrid selected row height While data in the DataGrid remains unchanged

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

On selection, I want to change DataGrid Selected row height. I used two methods. 1) I added an expander in DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="bookings_dg"  Expander.Expanded="Expander_Expanded"  IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.RowHeight>30</DataGrid.RowHeight>
```

Here is my Expander Event

```
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bookings_dg.RowHeight == 100)
        {
            bookings_dg.RowHeight = 20;
        }
        else
        {
            bookings_dg.RowHeight = 100;
        }

    }
```

it changes all rows size instead of specific one.

Then I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455361/how-to-increase-the-particular-row-height-in-the-wpf-datagrid-when-mouse-is-over) It changes height but also enlarges content in it.
Here is my datagrid before and after clicking. But i Want to change height of only selected row.[before img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ryL0.png)[After img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeb8C.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this with code behind. And don't use Scale unless you want it to look like a magnifying glass.

If all you want is to increase the row height when that row is selected, simple add a trigger to the row style so when selected they increase their own height.

```
<DataGrid Name="bookings_dg" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
            <Style.Triggers>   
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, there is a problem in it that it increases row height only but do not increases cells height in it.

Comment: It does for me. If I set a background color or border on the cell it fills the entire row. The text stays aligned to the Top Left position but that is because a TextBlock is being used internally in the DataGridCell to display it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: actually i want to increase the height of texBlock which is placed inside the row.